# How to UV unwrap a car model using standard perspectives?

Tags: uv

I made a low poly car model (772 tris, game asset) but I'd like to unwrap it so that I can use a single texture like this [car (no download, jpeg, 70 KB)](http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y21/aaronaton/IntegLowPolyPage.jpg).

Doing multiple "project from view" unwraps doesn't work since it deletes the last one. So what can I do with Blender?

Comment: Unwrapping only applies to the currently selected faces. If you want to unwrap the side view, only select the sides of the car, if you want to unwrap the front, only select the front. Then the UVs of the unselected faces will not be overwritten.

Comment: @maddin45 Ok but there isn't simply a front and side, there are "gray" areas. I'll try selecting by face.

Comment: Uhm no it's not working. Other solutions?

Comment: Well, for the gray areas you will have to decide which side you want to use. Otherwise it will get complicated (multiple UV coordinate sets and mixing materials and so on).

Comment: I have already asked this question! , Look through my questions and see if you canfind it

Comment: @Knuckles209cp Yeah I have seen it. :) I managed to solve unwrapping with seams in the end, but good to know. :)